# Django FormModel Validation

Tags: django

**Background**: Using the Django Admin framework, I'd like to run validation to make sure a record doesn't exist with the same values before saving.  Using a form, I added a check in the "clean" method.  That validation works exactly as I expect. I am successfully able to add NEW records and catch duplicates.

**THE PROBLEM**: The form is also validating the TabularInlines. Since the "parent page" isn't changed/updated it's not being sent and  it's not showing up in the "cleaned_data." Thus, when it's not checking to see if the parent record exists, it throws a KeyError.  IE, "hey, you said to check these parent variables and they aren't in here, wth?"

**Question**: Using forms, is there an elegant way to check the ModelAdmin (parent page) and the TabularInLines (child page) separately to avoid the key error?  OR do I just hard code checks for the different chunks if they exist? Different forms for different inlines? I'm providing some **PSEUDO CODE** below that should help outline the issue.

**DISCLAIMER**: The actual structure is more complicated. Yes, I realize in this EXAMPLE, there is a better way to handle this. However, I'm looking to solve the form validation issue.

```
##########
# Models 
##########

class Person(models.Model): 
   name = models.Char()

class Game(models.Model):
   gamename = models.Char()
   number_players = models.IntegerField()
   date = models.Date() 

class Record(models.Model): 
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person) 
   game = models.ForeignKey(Game) 
   attempt = models.IntegerField()
   won = models.BooleanField()
```

---

```
##########
# Admin.py 
##########

class PersonAdminInLine(admin.TabularInLine): 
    model = Person 

class GameAdminInline(admin.TabularInLine): 
    model = Game

class RecordAdmin(admin.Model.Admin): 
   model = Record 
   inlines = ['PersonAdminInline', 'GameAdminInlilne'] 

   form = RecordAdminForm 


admin.site.register(Record, RecordAdmin)
```

---

```
##########
# Form.py 
##########

class RecordAdminForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    def clean(self): 
        clean_data = self.cleaned_data 
        exists = Record.objects.filter(person = clean_data['person'], game = clean_data['game']).count()

        if exists >=1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("A record of this game already exists!")
    return cleaned_data
```

---

Let's say I altered the number of players, the type of error I'm getting will say "KeyError:person".  Assuming I explained this OK hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but you can use unique_together which sorta does the same thing.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together